# To make two door phones, extensions 105 and 106 dial a single extension 104 through an asterisk pbx

Tags: asterisk

I have the two door phones and the extension I wish them to call set up in asterisk, calls are possible to and from the door phones and from the extension.

My problem is that the door phones call the main switch board not the extension I want.

I have set up my sip.conf like so:

```
[104]
type=peer
secret=104
host=dynamic
context=intercom

[105]
type=peer
secret=105
host=dynamic
context=intercom

[106]
type=peer
secret=106
host=dynamic
context=intercom
```

and my extensions.conf like so:

```
[intercom]
include => dial-context

[dial-context]
exten => _1XX,1,answer()
exten => _1XX,n,dial(sip/${EXTEN})
exten => _1XX,n,hangup()
```

EDIT

Okay, so a little while later and some more reading.

I have removed the extensions.conf and changed the context in sip.conf to office
which is what the rest of extensions.conf is set to, this way at least the gate can call the main switchboard, until I learn more.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that most phones have a "hot line" number that you can program.  When the phone goes off hook, it dials that number automatically.  Set that to be your extension.

Alternately, you can do something like this:

```
[door_phones]
exten => _X.,1,Verbose(2,Forced dialing to the receptionist)
 same => n, Set(RECEPTION=106)
 same => n, dial(SIP/${RECEPTION})
 same => n, hangup()
```

Set the context for the two door phones to be "door_phones" and no matter what keys get pushed, the call will always go to "RECEPTION".

Answer (score 0):

Can you not set the intercoms to directly call the extension, i am not sure why they would call the main switch. with the intercom we use, through their own GUI you can set the call button to directly call an extension number. We use Castel and their [Asterisk Door Entry Phones](http://endpointwarehouse.com/). We also use [Paxton](http://www.paxton-access.com/) and their SIP NET. Paxton cant send DTMF in out of band though, which is a bit of a bummer !